# Is there a way of getting the instance of the object which created another object?

Tags: java, object

Lets say I have an application:

```
my_Application the_application = new my_Application();
Parser parser = new Parser;
parser.log();
```

And then, get some method parser.log() to throw a string into the application's window?

```
public void log(String input){
    // Get the instance of the object which created this object, call it 'daddy'
    daddy.log(input);
}
```

While in the original class of my_Application, there is a method `log`.

```
public void log(String input){
    textPane.append("[LOG] " + input);
}
```

Comment: No. There may not even be such an instance. Consider the case where it is constructed in a static method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your code stands, you can't. Your `parser` will need a reference to `the_application`. One way to do this is in the constructor:

```
public class Parser {
    private my_Application daddy = null;
    public Parser(my_Application app) {
        daddy = app;
    }

    public void log(String input){
        daddy.log(input);
    }
}
```

And then you create the parse like:

```
my_Application the_application = new my_Application();
Parser parser = new Parser(the_application);
```

As a side, declaring java classes with underscores is not a common practice. Rather use the convention of camelcase like `MyApplication`

Answer (score 0):

No, unless the created object holds some reference to its creator. There's no inherent connection.

Answer (score 0):

My best suggestion would be provide the "daddy" class to the constructor and ensure it implements an interface which has the void log(String input) method.

```
interface Logger{
    void log(String input);
}

public class Parser implements Logger{

    Logger parent;

    public Parser(Logger parent){
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    void log(String input){
        parent.log(input);
    }
}

public class my_Application implements Logger{
    void log(String input){
        textPane.append("[LOG] " + input);
    }

    public static void Main(String[] args){
        my_Application the_application = new my_Application();
        Parser parser = new Parser(the_application);
        parser.log();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the stacktrace to get this information

```
 StackTraceElement[] stackTraceElements = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()
```

According to the Javadocs:

> The last element of the array represents the bottom of the stack,
>   which is the least recent method invocation in the sequence.

A StackTraceElement has `getClassName()`, `getFileName()`, `getLineNumber()`
and `getMethodName()`.

See http://www.javaworld.com/article/2072391/the-surprisingly-simple-stacktraceelement.html for a tutorial

Although this answers your question, this will not help in the way that you want to call the parent method.  Assuming that you can use `reflection` you may be able to call the method.

Otherwise consider using

- A static method
- A link to the parent calling method by passing a reference to it.
- Inheritance?

Comment: @celticminstrel What do you mean `that`?

Comment: Well, the only time the method that created the object `new Parser()` can be guaranteed to be in the stack is during the constructor `Parser()`, right? You could call `parser.log()` from anywhere, not just a method of `my_Application`.

Comment: If the `daddy` object is calling the `Parser.log` method, then the `daddy` object will be on the stackTrace.  Throw an exception from (or use Eclipse to debug) `Parser.log` and you will see `daddy`

Comment: True, but the `Parser.log` method might've been called by something else.

Comment: Yes, and as per the question, that Object would need to create the object `Parser`  If the `log` method only needs to access `myApplication` then that is maybe a different question

Answer (score 0):

The most easy & friendly way: keep reference to the parent.

```
private Parent parentReference;
public Child(Parent parent)
{
    this.parentReference = parent;
}
```